# "spending for" VS "spending on"

Tags: prepositions

> 1. In 2018, spending **for** online advertising shot up by 16.6%.
> 2. In 2018, spending **on** online advertising shot up by 16.6%.

What's the difference between the two lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, really none. Generally we spend money **for** a *purpose*, or we spend money **on** a *thing*. But the distinction is a little muddled and, as in this case, you can often find both prepositions in use for the same thing.